# What specific algorithm is used in NumPy for the mean of an array, and what is its Big O?

Tags: python, numpy

For specifics of the question, I can't say since it's work related. I'm seeing some code at work that's using NumPy to compute a mean, along with some other tasks, and I want to rule out NumPy being the source of the O(n^2) behavior that I'm empirically observing in profiling this function.

I'm also curious about how NumPy computes the mean. Shouldn't there be real numerical stability issues in taking a mean of >1mil floats?

Comment: to take a mean of any dataset you have to 'visit' each item, therefore it's O(N). Sorting (don't get me started on BubbleSort!!) is often the cause  of O(N^2) behaviour

Comment: You can check its complexity by running a few tests of your own.

Comment: Mean is just sum divided by number of items.  When arrays get very large, speed can fall because memory management becomes more complex.  `numpy` can make a number of large temporary arrays when doing a series of calculations. `O` tests are best when the arrays are modest sized.

Comment: @hpaulj sadly the data here is huge. I definitely encountered the notion of mean in my math degrees, but I'm curious here if they're doing something more complicated to ensure numerical stability. I may be off on when large numbers in a double typed variable start to run into floating point issues, but it's a concern of mine here.

Comment: The `math.fsum` function worries about loss of precision, but the `numpy.sum` doesn't do anything special.  If you see anything different from a O(n) scaling I think has to do with memory limits, and will vary with machine and available ram.

Comment: Have you considered using Monte Carlo? https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/03/visualizing-montecarlo-simulation-results-mean-vs-median/